# Find the real height of an object by eyes

Tags: home-experiment, geometry, visualization

I wonder if I can get the height of an object (tree or a building) with the knowledge of:

- The distance between me and the object?
- The apparent height of that object?

Comment: What do you mean with apparent height?

Comment: I found this topic:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(visual)
the apparent height is the height as seen by eye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold a ruler or meter stick (real or imaginary) at the end of your arm.

Suppose you are 50 meters away from the object, and suppose your arm is 1 meter long.

Then take the height of the object as it appears on the ruler, and multiply by 50.

Comment: I found the answer 2 minutes after posting the question but wanted to make sure I got it right :)